# Railo 4.2.1.008 Error (missinginclude) what is going wrong?

Tags: java, tomcat, railo

I am very knew to Railo. But due to a job situation at work I got this app forced upon me to install on a Railo server which I gave an attempt to get this to work. But when I start with the installation of the app on the server and tried to access the install folder I get the following error:

```
Railo 4.2.1.008 Error (missinginclude)
======================================
Message     Page /install/index.cfm [/opt/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/install/index.cfm] not found
======================================
Java Stacktrace     Page /install/index.cfm [/opt/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/install/index.cfm] not found
at railo.runtime.PageSourceImpl.loadPage(PageSourceImpl.java:870):870
at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:905):905
at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.doInclude(PageContextImpl.java:861):861
at railo.runtime.listener.ModernAppListener._onRequest(ModernAppListener.java:206):206
at railo.runtime.listener.MixedAppListener.onRequest(MixedAppListener.java:18):18
at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2212):2212
at railo.runtime.PageContextImpl.execute(PageContextImpl.java:2179):2179
at railo.runtime.engine.CFMLEngineImpl.serviceCFML(CFMLEngineImpl.java:331):331
at railo.loader.servlet.CFMLServlet.service(CFMLServlet.java:29):29
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727):727
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303):303
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208):208
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52):52
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241):241
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208):208
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220):220
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122):122
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503):503
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170):170
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103):103
at mod_cfml.core.invoke(core.java:132):132
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950):950
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116):116
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421):421
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070):1070
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611):611
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316):316
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145):1145
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615):615
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61):61
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745):745
```

What is going wrong? Any ideas? If you require more details please ask.

My gut is telling me there is something going on between Apache and Tomcat/Railo but I am an absolute newby at this.

Comment: How did you install it? Using the installer or manually onto Tomcat using a WAR or JARs?

Comment: FYI, the Railo project is dead as well and has been forked (about 8 month ago) into a new project called Lucee (http://lucee.org)

Comment: First things first... is it right? Is `/opt/railo/tomcat/webapps/ROOT/install/index.cfm` there?

Comment: @Adam Cameron Yes the file is present at that location

Comment: @andrewdixon Railo was downloaded via the tar.gz file as indicated in their documentation for Linux. And from there I installed the .run file, if I recall it correctly

Comment: @iJar Well that sounds like the installer, so I'm not sure why you would get that. Don't think I have seen the `/install/index.cfm` before. Personally I would suggest removing it and trying the Lucee installer instead (http://lucee.org/downloads.html). The current version 4.5 of Lucee is basically exactly the same as Railo but with some bug and security fixes.

Comment: Nah, a tar.gz isn't the installer. Maybe the express edition? Although, I agree with Andrew's comment. The Lucee installer is probably going to be your best bet. It was designed to be easy to set up. Just install it to a fresh Linux install (Ubuntu/Debian or RHEL/CentOS, and Apache if you want it), and it does all of the config for you. Once it's installed, you just configure sites in Apache like normal, and the configuration for those is automatically translated to Tomcat/Lucee with mod_cfml. It's a pretty simple setup that easy to get up and running with. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to clean install Lucee and got it to work but by doing that I actually figured out what went wrong with my Railo configuration. During the installation I remembered it gave me a notification that it couldn't find my ServerName in the apache config file (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf). After doing this that one also worked. Hope this answer helps somebody else with the same issue I had.

Still, thank you for your help!